# Como puedo recuperar los datos de un textarea que tiene TinyMCE para dar formato del texto

Tags: php, tinymce, semantic-ui

Tengo un textarea al cual le aplico el plugin de edición de texto TinyMCE...
ahora bien... cuando quiero enviar a la base de datos el contenido de ese textarea, directamente me lo envía nulo...

En el Head cargo el siguiente script (esto lo saque de la configuración de la misma pagina de tinyMCE)

```
<script src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js?apiKey=ACA_VA_MI_KEY_DE_TINYMCE"></script>
  <script>
    tinymce.init({
    selector:'#resumen',
    language_url : '../../js/es.js'
  });

  tinymce.init({
    selector:'#texto',
    language_url : '../../js/es.js'
  });
</script>
```

Las textareas se llaman resumen y texto respectivamente.
Ahora bien... en las textareas tengo:

```
<div class="field">
  <label>Resumen / Bajada:</label>
  <textarea id="resumen" name="resumen" required>
  </textarea>
</div>
```

ese "id" lo que hace es enlazarme el script de tinyMCE

[image: Me queda asi]

abajo de todo tengo un boton de submit que mando por POST todo lo que se cargó en el formulario.

```
$error = "";
$fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
$resumen = nl2br($_POST['resumen']);
$texto = nl2br($_POST['texto']);
```

esto hago en el proceso de guardado... el 'resumen' y el 'texto' serian los dos textareas de los que defino en el script

---

NO ENTIENDO LO QUE PASA:
pasé en limpio el problema, e hice lo siguiente:

```
<head>
<title>My test editor - with tinyMCE and PHP</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "#texto",
        language_url : 'es.js',
        plugins: [
          'advlist autolink lists charmap print',
          'searchreplace code',
          'table contextmenu paste code pagebreak'
        ],
        toolbar: 'undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | pagebreak',
    });

    tinymce.init({
        selector: "#texto2",
        language_url : 'es.js',
        plugins: [
          'advlist autolink lists charmap print',
          'searchreplace code',
          'table contextmenu paste code pagebreak'
        ],
        toolbar: 'undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | pagebreak',
       });
     </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  <form method="post" action="proceso.php">
    <textarea id="texto" name="texto" rows="15" cols="80"></textarea>
    <textarea id="texto2" name="texto2" rows="15" cols="80"></textarea>

    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="save" value="Submit" />
    <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" />
    </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

despues en el proceso.pho hago lo siguiente:

```
<?php
session_start(); //Iniciar una nueva sesión o reanudar la existente
require 'conexion.php';

$allowedTags='<p><strong><em><u><h1><h2><h3><h4><h5><h6><img><li><ol><ul><span><div><br><ins><del><small>';
if($_POST['texto']!='') {
    $sContent = strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['texto']),$allowedTags);
    echo $sContent;
} else {
    $sContent = "";
}

if($_POST['texto2']!='') {
    $sContent2 = strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['texto2']),$allowedTags);
    echo $sContent2;
} else {
    $sContent = "";
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO temp (textarea, campo1) VALUES ('$sContent', '$sContent2')";
$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);

if($resultado) { 
    echo "todo perfecto";
} else{
    echo "error al guardar";
}

?>
```

ahora bien... funciona bien... guarda los datos en la base, pero en donde deberia funcionar, el boton submit no funciona !!! hago clic y nada... y es practicamente el mismo codigo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para enviar correctamente el texto área por PHP debes especificar los tags permitidos en el contenido, los detalles puedes verlos [aquí](https://www.tinymce.com/docs-3x/howto/TinyMCE3x@How-to_implement_TinyMCE_in_PHP/). Dejo una copia del código de ejemplo.

```
<?php
 $allowedTags='<p><strong><em><u><h1><h2><h3><h4><h5><h6><img>';
 $allowedTags.='<li><ol><ul><span><div><br><ins><del>';  
// Should use some proper HTML filtering here.
  if($_POST['elm1']!='') {
    $sHeader = '<h1>Ah, content is king.</h1>';
    $sContent = strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['elm1']),$allowedTags);
} else {
    $sHeader = '<h1>Nothing submitted yet</h1>';
    $sContent = '<p>Start typing...</p>';
    $sContent.= '<p><img width="107" height="108" border="0" src="/mediawiki/images/badge.png"';
    $sContent.= 'alt="TinyMCE button"/>This rover has crossed over</p>';
  }
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>My test editor - with tinyMCE and PHP</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  tinyMCE.init({
    theme : "advanced",
    mode: "exact",
    elements : "elm1",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,separator,"
    + "justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,formatselect,"
    + "bullist,numlist,outdent,indent",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "link,unlink,anchor,image,separator,"
    +"undo,redo,cleanup,code,separator,sub,sup,charmap",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
    height:"350px",
    width:"600px"
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
 <?php echo $sHeader;?>
 <h2>Sample using TinyMCE and PHP</h2>
 <form method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?>">
  <textarea id="elm1" name="elm1" rows="15" cols="80"><?php echo $sContent;?></textarea>
<br />
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Submit" />
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Otra opción es utilizar `tinyMCE.triggerSave();` antes de enviar el formulario. En este [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2266945/5675636) puedes ver algunos ejemplos.

Comment: muy amable @Carmen por responder !!!...

Comment: Para eso estamos @MNibor, me alegro que te haya servido

Answer (score 0):

Todo depende de cual sea la versión de tinyMCE que utilizas.

Suponiendo que cargas el tinyMCE con el siguiente código:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="tinymce.min.js"></script>
  <script>tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  plugins: [
    'textcolor colorpicker autoresize'
  ],
   toolbar: 'undo redo | styleselect | bold italic |  forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link'
});</script>

</head>
<body>
  <textarea></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Puedes usar **`javascript` puro**:

```
document.getElementById('mce_0_ifr').contentWindow.document.getElementById('tinymce').innerHTML
```

Comment: Cuando compartas tu código podemos modificar mi respuesta, y adaptarla al mismo

Comment: esto que me dices de "document.getelementbyid" (bla bla bla) me toma todo el contenido ? quiero decir con negritas, cursivas, etc ? pero como lo mando por post todo eso ? La version que uso es la ultima, me registre hace poco en la pagina de TinyMCE

Comment: @Mnibor ejecuta ese `javascript` y fijate lo que te devuelve: todo el código HTML. Para pasarlo por `post` debes ingeniarte para procesarlo mediante `javascript` y luego enviarlo al `post`. Esa es la manera en la que se me ocurre.